# Asp.Net WebApi Routing when published under DefaultWebSite and seperate WebSite

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

From Asp.Net MVC UI(View) I am calling a Asp.Net WebApi through Ajax Call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "api/UpdateEmployees",
    data: undefined,
    success:
        function () {
            EmployeesPage();
        },
    error: function (err) {
        Error(err);
    }
});
```

When I publish the WebSite in IIS as a Site it is working fine.But if I publish the WebSite under "Default Web Site" it is not working because it is expecting the url as "EmployeeWebSite/api/UpdateEmployees" where EmployeeWebSite is my virtual directory under "Default Web Site".

I should append url based on where the WebSite is hosted.Can anyone help me with this? I want my website to work in both cases.

I am deploying both ways using localhost.

Comment: What is the url of the host web page? What `url` is it posting to now? What `url` do you **want** it to post to?

Comment: Your question can be a bit more specific, I would say.

Answer (score -1):

use this code in layout.chtml or In your current View

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        var baseurl = '@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")';      
</script>
```

After that u can use your Base URL varible

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: baseurl +'api/UpdateEmployees',
    dataType: "json",    
    success:
        function () {
            EmployeesPage();
        },
    error: function (err) {
        Error(err);
    }
});
```

Tip : Dont put undefined in your $.ajax if you not parsing any data  Remove it  .
Have a grate day

Comment: Thanks a million.You are just superb.